# using URL Rewriting

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I am hosting 2 domain sites under one hosting server

```
\

 -Site1

 -Site2
```

I have 2 domains pointing to the hosting server.

e.g.

`site1.com` should point to `site1` folder
`site2.com` should point to `site2` folder.

currently at the root I have default file that would check if Request.ServerVariables("ServerName") is site1.com then redirect to (/site1)

so it shows `site1.com/site1/` and `site2.com/site2/`

How do I remove the subfolder? so it shows `site1.com` and `site2.com`?

I have looked into Using URL Rewriting,but I cant put the code together..... I believe each sub folder should have a `global.asax` file and in the  `Application_BeginRequest` I think I should do something.

Comment: Can't you just host it from `.../Site1/` as the app root instead of from the parent directory?

Comment: This is more an issue with IIS configuration than url rewriting.

Comment: Reason I am doing this is because I dont want to buy hosting severs for each site, they are tiny sites that would only require 1 hosting sever.. and the hosting server is pointing to the root folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Server.Transfer

code:

```
void appliaction_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    HttpRequest request = sender as HttpRequest;
     if（request.Url.Host.Contains("site1.com"))
     {
        request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Server.Transfer("site1.com/site1", true);
    }

  }
```

In the browser input site1.com